# How to transform object into array?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have an object which is dynamically built. I need to get some of the fields of this object (exactly the dynamic ones) and parse them into an array.

In the code below, I need to transform the towers[X] into an array of objects.

```
{id: "", description: "Teste", towers[1]: true, towers[2]: true, 
    towers[3]: true, …}
    description: "Test"
    id: ""
    towers[1]: true
    towers[2]: true
    towers[3]: true
    towers[4]: ""
}
```

I want it to be something like:

```
{
    id: ""
    description: "Test",
    towers[1]: true //Don't care if it stays here or not, will not use
    ...
}
```

And a new array like:

```
{
    [id: 1, value: true],
    [id: 2, value: true],
    [id: 3, value: true],
    [id: 4, value: ""]
}
```

Comment: Not enough information

Comment: The stuff at `And a new array like` is a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just going to guess towers[0] gives back a number, if it does you can do this. This will find all keys that have boolean values and keep them and append them to a object.

```
const obj = YOUROBJHERE;
Object.keys(obj ).filter((key) => tyepof obj[key] === "boolean").reduce((accum, key) => {
    return {...accum, [key]: obj[key]};
}, {})
```

Comment: That was close enough. I also have to consider that my question was not well elaborated. Thank you man!

Final result:
let towers = Object.keys(obj).filter((key) => key.indexOf('towers') != -1 && obj[key] == true).reduce((accum, key) => {
                        let towerId = key.replace('towers[', '').replace(']', '');
                        return {...accum, [towerId]: obj[key]};
                    }, {})

Comment: @Marcos if you don't want use reduce, replace... see my answer

Answer (score 0):

in case of X=number and obj is the object we want to transform

```
let result = [];
for (let indx = 1; indx <=x ; i++) {
result.push({value:indx,value: obj['towers'+indx]})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transform your array of object you can do some like:

```
   this.obj=this.obj.map(obj=>{
      return {
      id:obj.id,
      description:obj.description,
      towers:Object.keys(obj).filter((key) => key.indexOf('towers') != -1 )
          .map((k,index)=>{
              return {id:index+1,value:obj[k]}
          })
          .filter((x:any)=>x.value)
       }
    })
```

See that, map allow an "index" (begins by 0)